# How to use one text field in html form to search any column in database table

Tags: javascript, php, forms, radio-button, recordset

I'm trying to find out how to use one text field in my form to search any columns in my database table.

Right now it is just searching in sn column on my database table named stock. 
I need it to search column name  sn or user or status.

So, if you type  in a serial number and post form it will search my database and bring back results with no problems. But I want to be able to type a user's name or status and search my database that way too. So I was thinking of some how dynamically changing the 
Input name="" with maybe radio buttons to change the value to Input name="sn" or Input name="user" or Input name="status"  But I'm not sure how to do that.  I've been reading others saying with Javascript or JQuery. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

I have my recordset to query only sn column.  I'm sure I would need to change this too, but I'm not sure how.

The Form

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="search.php">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="sn" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
sn</label><br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="user" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
User</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="status" id="RadioGroup1_2" />
Staus</label>
<br />
</p>
<label for="sn"> Search :</label>
<input name="sn" type="text" id="sn" size="25" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The SQL

```
SELECT *
    FROM stock
    WHERE sn = colname
    ORDER BY `datetime` DES
```

The Php

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",             $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string    ($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;    
case "long":
case "int":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "double":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "date":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;
case "defined":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_Recordset567 = 10;
$pageNum_Recordset567 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset567'])) {
$pageNum_Recordset567 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset567'];
}
$startRow_Recordset567 = $pageNum_Recordset567 * $maxRows_Recordset567;

$colname_Recordset567 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['sn'])) {
$colname_Recordset567 = $_GET['sn'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_stock, $stock);
$query_Recordset567 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE sn = %s ORDER BY  `datetime`  DESC", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset567, "text"));
$query_limit_Recordset567 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset567,    $startRow_Recordset567, $maxRows_Recordset567);
$Recordset567 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset567, $stock) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset567 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset567);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset567'])) {
$totalRows_Recordset567 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset567'];
} else {
$all_Recordset567 = mysql_query($query_Recordset567);
$totalRows_Recordset567 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset567);
}
$totalPages_Recordset567 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset567/$maxRows_Recordset567)-1;
?>
```

Comment: You have a form without any associated javascript -- This form will submit immediately to _search.php_. What you want to do, instead, is prevent the form submission with javascript/jquery then test your field value. Is the value a SN/Name/Status? After you have determined that populate separate hidden fields, submit, and build your search on those values.

Comment: Or just use radio buttons on the form.

Answer (score 1):

the radiobuttons are a good idea... Make sure they all have the same name. Then use php to identify which value belongs to which action. Make sure you secure all data in the input.
You could also use the mysql term OR to search in different columns at once.
Here is your php:

```
$radioVal = $_POST['radiobtnVal'];
switch $radioVal{
    case 1 :
        $col = "sn";    //don't directly write to the variable here, since that would make a security risk
        break;
    case 2 :
        $col = "user";
        break;
    case 3 :
        $col = "status";
        break;
}

//now make connection to your database
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['searchString']);    //This will secure your input from mysql injections
//$db is the variable you made during connection with your database
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `Stock` WHERE `" . $col . "`='" . $search . "'");

//or use the mentioned OR term
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `Stock` WHERE `sn`='" . $search . "' OR `user`='" . $search . "' OR `status`='" . $search . "'");
//Note that if some search strings are in multiple columns all these rows will be selected
```

I hope this helps

Comment: ok thanks so, I should do,( WHERE sn or user or status = colname ) right? also can you give ex how to write out the code using php for the radio buttons

Comment: Thanks looks good. how can I incorate this on my current php I have now. Im using dreamweaver and recordsets.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dreamweaver, and I don't understand all the php code that you have written. The code that I gave you just gets the result by using a mysql query, so you should put this code on the place where you have written your mysql query...

Comment: Make sure you have made connection with your database, before using this code, and change $db to the variable you used for your database connection.

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic way of doing that and its a good user experience.
Try this solution.

FORM

```
<Form action="search.php" method="post">
    <label>Serial</label>
    <input name='search' type='text' size='25'/>
    <button type='submit'>Search</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$searchColumns = array();
//Will add Serial Number if # was found on search
if(!(strpos("#",$search)===FALSE)){
    $searchColumns[] = "sn = '{$search}'";
}
//Will add Status to select if there is no spaces in search.
if(count(explode(" ",$search))==1){
    $searchColumns[] = "status = '{$search}'";
}
//Will add user to select if its not a Serial search
//And if its has more than 5 chars (change it to your min char username)
if(strpos("#",$search)===FALSE && strlen($search) > 5){
    $searchColumns[] = "user = '{$search}'";
}

$sql = "
SELECT *
  FROM stock
 WHERE ".(implode(" AND ",$searchColumns))."
 ORDER BY datetime DES";

?>
```